# API LinkedIn and Data scraping

Tags: web-scraping, linkedin-api

I'm exploring the legality of scraping job postings and public posts from LinkedIn. Could you clarify whether this activity is permitted, and under what conditions, if any? Additionally, I'm interested in understanding how the LinkedIn API functions for individuals. My goal is to collect information on recent job openings for a list of companies I'm interested in. Could you advise on how to accomplish this legally?

I read different articles.

Comment: This is an extremely broad question, as it varies depending on what your location is. It also depends on how you are using the data. LinkedIn's terms of service aren't the law of the land, so they can ban you or block your IP, but that doesn't necessarily mean you're a criminal. See the relevant LinkedIn court case regarding web scraping: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HiQ_Labs_v._LinkedIn